# Trace radio interface events log without having root privileges

Tags: android, ril

I need to trace radio interface events log without having root privileges. It would be great to have the lowest layer protocol trace we can get ( e.g. AT commands or call control protocol).
I have 2 devices: OS Android 4.0.3, OS Android 2.3.4

Is it possible? How can I get such a trace? Have you had such a problem? What was the decision?

Appreciate any reply you will post for the topic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get radio logs you can use the follow command:

```
$ adb logcat -v time -b radio
```